# Cloning output of a terminal

Tags: console

I need to do a presentation over Skype of a command line tool over a fairly flaky mobile connection, since I'm currently traveling. I would like to avoid screen sharing to maximize bandwidth for audio and instead get the copy of my output straight to a terminal on the other end.

Essentially we have a Linux server X, where the tool is installed and I have root access to it if needed. What I would like is to log in to the server and someone from the room receiving the presentation would do the same. Using some method the output of my console would then be mirrored on their console. It's important that scrolling also works using less, i.e. that I can pipe the output through less and step through it and also back up if needed.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Typical job for [GNU `screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Session-Management.html#Session-Management).

Answer (score 5):

I've used `tmate` which is based on `tmux` successfully to share terminal during remote pair programing sessions. Google hangout's will also allow sharing of a single window, although I have the impression it uses more bandwidth.

http://tmate.io